# Using Accent colors instead of RGB values in PPT VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I found this code to apply current slide layout's title formats to all slides of the ppt, but is there any way to set the accent colors instead of RGB values to the title fonts? .ObjectThemeColor or .SchemeColor not works in this instance.
able to get RGB values but not SchemeColor, here ocust value becomes null.

[image]

```
Sub AlignToMaster()
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim oshp As Shape
    Dim ocust As Shape
    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If osld.Shapes.HasTitle Then
            Set oshp = osld.Shapes.Title
            Set ocust = osld.CustomLayout.Shapes.Title
            With oshp
                .Left = ocust.Left
                .Top = ocust.Top
                .Height = ocust.Height
                .Width = ocust.Width
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = ocust.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = ocust.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ocust.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ocust.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = ocust.Line.ForeColor.RGB
            End With
        End If
    Next osld
    MsgBox ("All titles have been adjusted to the master slide format")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

**SchemeColor** is what you're after. "not works in this instance" doesn't tell us anything, please describe any error messages or whatever unexpected results you're getting. Here's the syntax for using Accent Colors:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = ppAccent1
```

Here's the Microsoft reference page showing the parameters you can use to access the other theme colors: [ColorFormat.SchemeColor property (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.colorformat.schemecolor)

Revision:
To get the scheme color, here is the syntax:

```
MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor
```

Comment: Hi John, added the error screenshot and details to the original post. I can assign ppAccent1 to schemecolor but unable to get value from another shape as per my code.

Comment: That's not what your post originally said. There is nothing in your existing code that even attempts to get a schemecolor from an object. And you haven't told us which line raises the error.

Comment: yes, my mistake, this line gives the error, unable to change this RGB values to schemeColor

.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ocust.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB

Comment: Set oScolor = ocust.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.SchemeColor
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.SchemeColor = oScolor

I have added this code as you said, but not working

Comment: Fill.Color is not in the object model, use Fill.ForeColor instead.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too earlier if you see the first comment, and I found this object model in MSDN, could you please test this code above, its not working.

Comment: Your posted code references RGB colors, not theme/scheme colors, so it couldn't possible do what you're requesting. I've tested the code I posted and it works. How about if you post your current version, along with whatever error message you're getting and which line triggers it.